# How to compress with 7zip instead of zip, code changing

Tags: python

I have a code that compress every file in a specific folder with zip but I want to compress it with 7zip, so how to do ?

This is what I have so far:

```
for date in dict_date:#zipping folders and get same name like the folder
    with ZipFile(os.path.join(src, '{0}.7z'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
        for subFolder in dict_date[date]:
            for fil in os.listdir(os.path.join(src, date, subFolder)):
                if not fil.endswith('.7z'):
                    myzip.write(os.path.join(src, date, subFolder, fil))
```

Comment: changing the file extension will not change the file format nor compression algorithm used. you will have to call the 7zip command line client via a subprocess call.

Answer (score 13):

You can try the command line method

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', filename+'.7z', filename])
```

or for all files in folder

```
subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', filename+'.7z', "*.*"])
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a good Python module for creating a 7z archive (despite what the documentation says, py7zlib can only *read* them).

A workaround is to download the 7z SDK (http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and use the 7zr executables that come with it via the subprocess module. 7z is in the public domain so you can carry this standalone program around without restriction.

Comment: It appears that might work on Linux – but not Windows.