# How to create *.7z file in Python?

Tags: python, 7zip, lzma

**How to create *.7z file in Python?**
Please write an small-simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [py7zr](https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr/), which supports 7zip archive compression, decompression, encryption, decryption. https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr

For .7z creation, use this code:

```
import py7zr
with py7zr.SevenZipFile('target.7z', 'w') as z:
    z.writeall('./base_dir')
```

Answer (score -1):

You need [py7zlib](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/py7zlib.py), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466572/python-how-to-compress-with-7zip-instead-of-zip-code-changing)

Comment: Looks to me like py7zlib does not write 7z archives - it only reads them. If I'm mistaken, can somebody post some code on how to use it to write one?