# Unzipping file results in "BadZipFile"

Tags: python, zip, unzip, compression

I know there are similar questions but neither of them provided a solution for my problem. I am using the following code:

```
import os, glob
import zipfile

root = 'E:\\xx\\fashion\\*'
directory = 'E:\\xx\\fashion\\'
extension = ".zip"

date_file_list = []
for folder in glob.glob(root):
    if folder.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
        print(folder)
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory, folder)).extractall(os.path.join(directory, os.path.splitext(folder)[0]))
        os.remove(folder) # delete zipped file_name
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xx/unzip.py", line 12, in <module>
    zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory, folder)).extractall(os.path.join(directory, os.path.splitext(folder)[0]))
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", line 1094, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Some of the files are compressed in winzip some of them are in 7zip. But there are too many files to unzip. 
Anybody know why this error is occurring?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798010/5320906

Comment: But I think my script skips if the extension is .7z right?

Comment: So the problem is with the files that has .zip extension