# I want to decompress 7z file and change img(in 7z) to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.5, 7zip

I installed 7z file in kaggle.
But I don't know how to use 7z file in python3.
I want to decompress 7z file and change img(in 7z) to numpy array.

please help me.

https://www.kaggle.com/rhammell/planesnet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read contents of 7z file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797851/how-to-read-contents-of-7z-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import cv2  # pip install cv2

def get_images(path_to_7z_file):
    # in windows would be something like C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
    # for linux /usr/local/bin/7z. check it using "which" command
    exe_7z = r'path/to/7z/executable' 
    # x is for extracting, you can use other 7zip flags, check "7z --help" command
    subprocess_args = ('%s x %s' % (exe_7z, s7z_file)).split(' ')
    process_7z = subprocess.Popen(subprocess_args)
    ret_code = process_7z.wait()
    if ret_code != 0:
        # maybe the system could not find the 7z executable
        # or the 7z file could not be opened
        print 'error in 7z command' 
    else:
        img_files = [
            f for f in os.listdir('.')
            if (os.path.isfile(f) and 
                f.split('.')[1].lower() in ['png', 'jpg']) # other extensions
        ]
        # img_files holds the list of images within the 7z archive
        for img_file in img_files:
            img = cv2.imread(img_file) 
            # at this point, img is a numpy.array
```

you can use `Pillow` or `cv2` to work with images. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762948/how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-numpy-array) for more info.

Comment: pip install opencv-python??

Comment: Yes. My bad.          :)