# Mimic 7zip with python

Tags: python, 7zip, lzma

I am using Python 3.6, and currently I subprocess out to my 7zip program to get the compression I need.

`subprocess.call('7z a -t7z -ms=off {0} *'.format(filename))`

I know the zipfile class has ‘ZIP_LZMA’ compression, but the application I am passing this too says the output file isn’t correct.  So what else do I have to add to the ZipFile class to make it mimic the above command?

Comment: ZIP files are different from 7Z files. Even if ZIPs might support LZMA compression these days, the files are still different. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797851/how-to-read-contents-of-7z-file-using-python maybe?

Comment: Is there any packages to do 7zip compression?

Comment: @codebase5000, this library perhaps https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma ?

Comment: Pylzma is a good suggestion

Comment: @TarunLalwani So i tried pylzma, and can't seem to figure it out.  Can you post a sample?

Comment: @codebase5000, just figured it out, it is a read 7z file and not write 7z file. And I have tried digging but couldn't find one such reference to a library which writes to a 7z file

Comment: Maybe I should increase the bounty, sounds like python really needs this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care much for Windows, then perhaps [libarchive](https://github.com/Changaco/python-libarchive-c) could help. In Ubuntu, for example:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-libarchive-c
```

Then:

```
import libarchive
with libarchive.file_writer('test.7z', '7zip') as archive:
    archive.add_files('first.file', 'second.file', 'third.file')
```

Then there is the [pylib7zip](https://github.com/harvimt/pylib7zip) library, which wraps the existing `7z.dll` and seems to offer a Windows-only alternative.

Comment: Also lib archive-c seems to fail on build

Comment: Pylib7zip is a wrapper around 7z.dll, hence in theory one should be able to squeeze the compression out of it as well - the existence of the FileOutStream class does give some hope.

Comment: To build python_libarchive_c you'd probably need to install the necessary dependencies (e.g. libarchive-dev). The pre-built Ubuntu package somehow works, after all.