# How can I use PPMD compression for text files in Python?

Tags: python, compression

I would love to use PPMd compression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching) in a Python script that saves log files (since PPMD is amazing at compressing text/log files).

However, I can't seem to find any library that implements this. I have found a gzip library, but this is slower and worse than PPMd for my situation.

If there is no library for PPMd compression, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: What is PPMD compression?

Comment: @Swaroop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python core offers some compression algorithms, but PPMd is not supported yet. [[1](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py7zr.html)]

You could anyhow call eg. 7zip with the `subprocess` module. Here is an example on how to use 7zip with PPMd in the command line:

`7z a -m0=PPMd archive.7z text.txt`

You also might want to have a look at this answer [Mimic 7zip with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424946/mimic-7zip-with-python/50497509#50497509) where two Python libraries for using 7zip are mentioned, but the first one only works on Linux and the other only on Windows.

Comment: I just saw this blogpost, where somebody posted hist implementation of PPMd in Python: https://encode.su/threads/1583-diz-py-release