# How to effectively iterate through a 7z archive reading all files without extracting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, zip, brotli

I have a 7z archive containing plenty of JSONs. What's the most effective (=fastest) way to iterate through the archive and read every single JSON?

My aim is to extract a certain key from every single JSON in the archive, preferably without extracting and saving the uncompressed files to disk. The result should be a pickled pandas dataframe.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797851/how-to-read-contents-of-7z-file-using-python) question probably points in the right direction by using [py7zr](https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr). I found the [readall()](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#py7zr.SevenZipFile.readall)-method but something seems to go wrong.

```
import py7zr
import re
from py7zr import FILTER_BROTLI

filters = [{'id': FILTER_BROTLI, 'level': 9}]

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('testzip.7z', 'r', filters=filters) as zip:
    for fname, bio in zip.readall().items():
        print('{:s}: {:X}...'.format(name, bio.read(10)))
```

Only returns

```
UnsupportedCompressionMethodError: Unauthorized and modified Brotli data (skipable frame) found.
```

Seems like there are some issues with Brotli. Any clues?

Comment: I created the file through 7zip GUI (Brotli as compression, level 9). The [docs](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#compression-methods) claim that Brotli is supported however.